# Computing moving average for a specific last n duration in java

Tags: java, formula, moving-average, computation

I have encountered an use case wherein i am supposed to calculate moving average for a specific duration, say for last n days. I know this can be accomplished easily if i store all the past data that i can subtract the contribution corresponding to the previous days. But how do i effectively compute it only storing the previous days average without the previous data.
Below is what I want to accomplish
Say for example I have 5 days of data like 2, 8, 5, 2, 5 and its average is 4.4
Now If have a eighth day's data to be 10 then running average should be calculated leaving out the elements first 3 elements 2, 8 and 5 and thus average will be 3.2
Currently I employ an approach of determining average contribution corresponding to a day and subtract it with total average which i feel is inaccurate

```
 Formula = (avg for past n days) +  (today's count/n) - 
-(no_of_days from the last computed day * (avg for past n days)/n)
```

So can someone please suggest me an effective implementation/computation formula for achieving this?

Comment: Isn't this more of an algorithm question? Perhaps it belongs to another StackExchange site?

Comment: ya and sorry.. will post it there..

Comment: If you're retaining *only* the previous average, what you're asking for is simply not possible.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I have been able to do it. It's more of an estimation and so it is inaccurate

Comment: ur results will obviously be an estimate, So rather than concerning urself with some complex algorithm use a simple one. here is my suggestion.((avg for past n days) + (last day)) / 2

Comment: Sure, one can compute any number of inaccurate metrics. But if you want an *estimate*, your question should say that. Why not use a standard approach, such as an *exponential moving average*?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth So accuracy can only be attained by persisting the previous data and computing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how do i effectively compute it only storing the previous days average without the previous data.

You can't.  A simple rolling average or moving average requires you to remember all values in the interval.  There is no (useful)<sup>1</sup> formula that allows you to do otherwise.

However that's not the end of it.  There are other rolling-average measures that don't require you to store all of the values; e.g. "weighted moving average", "cumulative moving average", "exponential moving average" and so on.  The Wikipedia on [Moving Averages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) gives a good overview, describing the properties of the various measures and providing formulae.

I suggest you read the page, and then make your choice.  Implementing any one of the rolling average measures in Java should be a simple programming task.

---

<sup>1 - You could invent a useless one ... that relied on storing N other values derived from the original ones.  But I don't think that will help.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible, you've thrown away the data so cannot magically get it back.

You could calculate a moving average simply by doing:

```
averageSoFar = (averageSoFar+scoreForToday) / 2
```

That heavily weighs it towards today though so what you probably want is a ratio for how much to take from today and how much from the average so far. For example if you want a 10 day moving average then a starting point for that will be 0.1

```
averageSoFar = averageSoFar *(1-weightingFactor)+scoreForToday*weightingFactor
```

Really you should either keep the data or look up proper algorithms for exactly what you need though.